# DNS is not propagating correctly

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

I bought a hosting and a domain. The hosting company provide me a Name Server which I put in domain. Know its has been 1 month, the DNS is not propagating correctly across Internet. It is partial is some parts of the world.
[Here is the screenshot of DNS propagation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKYtG.jpg)

What is the problem with propagation.

Comment: Check if your configuration is OK with https://intodns.com/

Comment: Probably relevant: https://dnsviz.net/d/bazar9.pk/dnssec/

Comment: There is no "DNS propagation" as the DNS is not top down. What matters is only TTLs. Do not post links to screenshots. You can fully debug things by using `dig`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The glue records for the nameservers in use do not match the authoritative records.

If we look at the tail end of `dig +trace +all` output, this is clearly visible:

```
$ dig +trace +all bazar9.pk NS

; <<>> DiG 9.11.14-RedHat-9.11.14-2.fc31 <<>> +trace +all bazar9.pk NS

[snip]


;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11585
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bazar9.pk.                     IN      NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
bazar9.pk.              38400   IN      NS      ns1.letout.com.pk.
bazar9.pk.              38400   IN      NS      ns2.letout.com.pk.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.letout.com.pk.      38400   IN      A       207.180.245.14
ns2.letout.com.pk.      38400   IN      A       207.180.245.14

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 185.159.197.160#53(185.159.197.160)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 25 16:16:59 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9383
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 1680
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bazar9.pk.                     IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bazar9.pk.              86400   IN      NS      ns2.letout.com.pk.
bazar9.pk.              86400   IN      NS      ns1.letout.com.pk.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.letout.com.pk.      14400   IN      A       144.91.98.31
ns2.letout.com.pk.      14400   IN      A       144.91.98.31

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 144.91.98.31#53(144.91.98.31)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 25 16:16:59 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117
```

Do note how the glue records for the "nameservers" point to `207.180.245.14`, while the authoritative records point to `144.91.98.31`. These sets of records must match for things to work in a consistent manner.

The glue records are managed through the registrar for the domain that the nameserver names belong to (`letout.com.pk` in your case), while the authoritative records are in the actual `letout.com.pk` zone.

Also note that while there are two `NS` records pointing to two names, there clearly is just one nameserver as the address records (`A`/`AAAA`) are identical.
This ought to be fixed as well to avoid a single point of failure.

Comment: I don't know any thing about these records. Why nameservers are pointing to another ip? How this problem will be solved? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah The short story is that if you are new to DNS you should probably for now use a provider to handle the nameservers on your behalf instead of trying to do it yourself. Specifically with glues, which can be difficult. If you really want to fix things by yourself you will either need to publish proper IP addresses in your own zone (same ones as in the glue) or make the owner of `letout.com.pk` go through its registrar and change/remove the glues (remove can't happen until your domain, and maybe others stop using those nameservers)